# Return Array based on Dates and Criteria

Tags: regex, filter, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

[image: Raw Data]
[image: Where Data Array Will Retun]

I am creating an expense and income sheet using google form. My family will be able to track their purchases and income using a simple form, but on the backend, I want to organize the data a little better.

I need my sheet to read the raw data, lookup data between certain dates and return an array of those items. The problem is I can look up and return everything, but I only want to return specific columns. (I want to have separate Expense and Revenue Columns)

I've tried using a filter function, which works for looking up items between specific dates but it returns all the data in the sheet.

```
=FILTER('Form Raw Data'!A3:M6, 'Form Raw Data'!C3:C6 >=C1, 'Form Raw Data'!C3:C6 <=D1)
```

In an ideal world, the Formula would only return the array of items that are labeled as Expense or Income. Even if I can get only the rows that show those 2 categories, I can hide the excess columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cell **A9**:

```
=QUERY('Form Raw Data'!A3:M, "select B,C,G,H where D = 'Expense'", 0)
```

cell **G9**:

```
=QUERY('Form Raw Data'!A3:M, "select B,C,F,H where D = 'Income'", 0)
```

[image: 0]

with date ranges **A9**:

```
=QUERY('Form Raw Data'!A3:M, 
 "select B,C,G,H 
  where D = 'Expense' 
    and C >= date '"&TEXT(C1, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"' 
    and C <= date '"&TEXT(D1, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'", 0)
```

with date ranges **G9**:

```
=QUERY('Form Raw Data'!A3:M, 
 "select B,C,F,H 
  where D = 'Income' 
    and C >= date '"&TEXT(C1, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"' 
    and C <= date '"&TEXT(D1, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'", 0)
```

Comment: sure can! 

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10J0d49IZLJIOwKVKBTCKr0dOfTmkHDSZgTf5ZZ4QVOk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: FREAKING AWESOME.... never even thought about trying a query ... thank you SOOOOO MUCH!

Comment: I'll work on adding the filter to it now so that it only looks up dates between the range... the Raw data will be a running sheet with 1000s of lines of transactions, but I will be making multiple sheets representing all the months... if that makes sense